# Imprimir desde API en c# usando .Net 7

Tags: api, asp.net-core, c#-8.0

Estoy realizando un API que sirve de comunicación entre un punto de venta local de windows y un punto de venta igual local pero de app Android, el tema es que al momento de que guardo la comanda de una mesa ocupo imprimir esa misma comanda, eh intentado varias maneras la ultima seria la siguiente:

```
public void Main(string puertoImp)
        {
            string impresora = string.Format(@$"\\{puertoImp}"); // Reemplaza con la IP o el nombre del puerto USB de tu impresora
            string textoAImprimir = "Texto de ejemplo\nNueva línea\tTabulación\rRetorno de carro";

            try
            {
                PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
                printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = impresora;
                printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
                    stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(textoAImprimir, new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, stringFormat);
                };

                printDocument.Print();
                Console.WriteLine("Texto enviado a la impresora.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error al imprimir: {ex.Message}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

la idea es reemplazar la cadena de texto fija por una cadena de texto con la comanda pero con todas las maneras que he intentado me muestra siempre el siguiente error:

> "System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'libcups' or one of its dependencies: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado. (0x8007007E)'"

Por lo general es al ejecutar la linea "printDocument.Print();", si alguien tuviera información del error lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Un par de preguntas: ¿Ese código se ejecuta en Windows? ¿Tienes añadida la referencia de NuGet a System.Drawing.Common en el .csproj?

Comment: @ArielCostas Ya lo resolví, en efecto tenia que ver con la referencia de NuGet, al parecer a la hora de la instalación algo trono y no se instalo correctamente, tuve que desinstalar la referencia y reinstalarla para que funcionara, mil gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Ok, agrego respuesta para que quede la pregunta como solucionada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que comentaste, faltaba la referencia al paquete `System.Drawing.Common` de NuGet. Añadirlo al `.csproj` fue suficiente para arreglar el problema.